# post asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, post, server-side

I have an aspx page. In  tag i wrote action property to some url.
   There is a submit button, when i press it the page is submitted. This is quite simple....
   But what i will do when i have to submit that page to three different URLs upon pressing three different submit buttons? How would i handle the action property of  tag for three different URLs. Can i submit form from server side?(I mean by changing action property of form dynamically).
I am new to asp.net please help me as soon as possible.
I will be thankful to you...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the PostBackUrl-Property as explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx